# chrome extension inline installation broken on chrome 58

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We are using the inline installation to install our chrome extension. It worked (and is still working) for chrome 57 and lower. However, on the new chrome version 58 the inline installation stopped working.

I can:

- install the extension manually from the web store
- install the extension inline on chrome 57 and lower

This is our setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link   href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/<id>" rel="chrome-webstore-item">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="installExtension()">
<script>
    var chromeExtensionUrl  = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/<id>";
    function installExtension() {
        chrome.webstore.install(chromeExtensionUrl,
            function() {
                startCountdown();
                sessionLog("extensionInstallAccepted");
            },
            function(aErr) {
                console.log(aErr);
            });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i click the button i recieve the error:

```
Could not fetch data from the Chrome Web Store
```

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Edit:

after going through https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=705283# some more info

- i can install the extension inline on v58 if i logout of my google account

Comment: Is that your case [crbug.com/705283](https://crbug.com/705283) ?

Comment: looks very likely, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself here as i'm pretty sure there is not much that can be done.

It is very likely a bug in chrome itself. The only thing you can do is not using the inline installation or require your user to log out of their google accounts before installing.

See

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=714176#
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=705283#